# Script containing a contact form will only run once; how can I make it load in multiple places?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, contact-form

I have the below embed for a script that runs a contact form. I want the form to be permanently showing on my page at the top, but further down the page I want to be able to press a button that launches a pop-up with the form. However, because the form is already loaded further up the page, the popup will launch but the script will not run and load the form.

```
<div id="form_98695b88-54e6-45df-84b9-50efc7b51e2d" style="min-width: 500px; max-width: 525px;">Loading...</div>
<script async="async" src="https://slate.wichita.edu/register/?id=98695b88-54e6-45df-84b9-50efc7b51e2d&amp;output=embed&amp;div=form_98695b88-54e6-45df-84b9-50efc7b51e2d">/**/</script>
```

Is there anything I can do to the HTML or a new function I can add to the site so that the form will load a second time in the popup?

The script is running just fine in the on-page form. The same embed HTML was added to a popup that triggers after you click a button. The popup launched just fine, but the text was left on "Loading..." with the script not running.

Comment: You'll want to add an event listener to the pop-up to run the script when it's displayed.

Comment: Ids need to be unique so I'd suggest replacing all occurences of `form_98695b88-54e6-45df-84b9-50efc7b51e2d` with a new id.

Comment: ids are singular so if it is using same id, it will not work.